# Pandas DataFrame from raw string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I've got a string which looks like:

```
a1\tb1\tc1\na2\tb2\tc2\na3\tb3\tc3\n...
```

Is there an efficient and smart way to convert this kind of string into a Pandas DataFrame? StringIO seems not to be correct for this approach.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `"StringIO seems not to be correct for this approach."` - why do you think so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StringIO` works perfectly.

```
import io

string = 'a1\tb1\tc1\na2\tb2\tc2\na3\tb3\tc3'
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

    0   1   2
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a2  b2  c2
2  a3  b3  c3
```

---

You can also use `pd.read_table` or `pd.read_fwf` in the same manner:

```
pd.read_table(io.StringIO(string), header=None)
```

Or,

```
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(string), header=None)
```

```
    0   1   2
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a2  b2  c2
2  a3  b3  c3
```

In these last two examples, it is assumed that whitespace is the natural delimiter. However, your raw string must maintain a consistent structure within data.

---

Finally, you can also use a string splitting approach, splitting on newlines first, and then on tabs:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(map(str.split, string.splitlines())))

    0   1   2
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a2  b2  c2
2  a3  b3  c3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Problem was I was not coding the unicode conversion and delim_whitespace. By the way, which approach do you thinkg its more efficient and fast: splitting aproach or read_csv? Thank you!!

Comment: @P.Solar `StringIO` simulates IO, so I think it will be a lot slower than string splitting. I would suggest timing this on your data. The string splitting won't work if your values/cells also have spaces in them.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2.7**

You just need to specify the delimiter to be `sep='\t'` and also put the string to unicode to avoid errors:

```
 pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u'a1\tb1\tc1\na2\tb2\tc2\na3\tb3\tc3'), 
             sep="\t", header=None)
    0   1   2
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a2  b2  c2
2  a3  b3  c3
```

Comment: "put the string to unicode" isn't always this easy when you're receiving data from some external source. It may not be a problem in this case.

Comment: If not unicode I got this error: `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: Are you using python2? :)

Comment: You're right, I run python3 on Jupyter, but now I was on iPython terminal. Turns out the kernel was python2.7. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Indeed, I was using a string as result of SamTools execution. In this case, pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(unicode(results, 'utf-8')), delim_whitespace=True) will work.